# how can i put my my binary, octal, and Hexadecimal in one loop

Tags: java

So my goal this week was to find the hexadecimal octal and binary for decimal. I was able to get the hexdecimal, binary, and octal but were individual loops on different public class. So i was wondering how could i make this code one and read the hexadecimal, octal, and binary all in one loop.

---

decimal to hexadecimal

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class uncode {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
    int decimal = input.nextInt();

    String hex = "";

    while (decimal != 0 ) {
        int hexValue = decimal % 16;

        char hexDigit = (hexValue <= 9 && hexValue > 0) ?
                (char) (hexValue + '0') : (char)(hexValue - 10 + 'A');

                hex = hexDigit + hex;

                decimal = decimal / 16;
        }
    System.out.println("The hex number is " + hex);
    }
}
```

---

decimal to octal

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class octal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        String octal = "";

        while ( decimal > 0 ) {
            int remainder = decimal % 8;
            octal = remainder + octal;

            decimal = decimal / 8;
        }
        System.out.println("Octal number:  " + octal);
    }

}
```

---

decimal to binary

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class GuessNumbers {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
            int decimal = input.nextInt();
            String binary = "";
            while (decimal > 0) {
                int remainder = decimal % 2;
                binary = remainder + binary;
                decimal = decimal / 2;
            }
            System.out.println("Binary number: " + binary);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%d %s %s%n", decimal, Integer.toOctalString(decimal), Integer.toHexString(decimal));`

Comment: you needn't use one loop for these purposes, you could make 3 simple methods that receive a decimal number and return the corresponding value

Comment: @AndrewTobilko how would i do that?

Comment: @MikeShasaco, `while ( decimal1 > 0 || decimal2 > 0 || decimal3 > 0 )` and there is a `if` inside for each case, but that is **not good** idea

Comment: @AndrewTobilko oh i see my assignment was to Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter a decimal integer and displays its corresponding binary, octal, and hexadecimal numbers. You have to use a loop structure and not any conversion functions or methods. So i was just trying to see whats the best way

Answer (score 1):

Easy way would be to use already present converstions, for example

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
int decimal = input.nextInt();
String hex = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
String oct = Integer.toOctalString(decimal);
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
```

If you need an integer value, not the string, you can use

```
int h = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
int o = Integer.parseInt(oct, 8);
int b = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
```

Assuming you don't want to use these methods (let's say you have your reasons).

First, you need to put your code in a method, not inside main.

Then you can do something like this:

```
public class Class {
    public static void uncode() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();

        String hex = "";

        while (decimal != 0) {
            int hexValue = decimal % 16;

            char hexDigit = (hexValue <= 9 && hexValue > 0) ? (char) (hexValue + '0')
                    : (char) (hexValue - 10 + 'A');

            hex = hexDigit + hex;

            decimal = decimal / 16;
        }
        System.out.println("The hex number is " + hex);
    }

    public static void octal() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        String octal = "";

        while (decimal > 0) {
            int remainder = decimal % 8;
            octal = remainder + octal;

            decimal = decimal / 8;
        }
        System.out.println("Octal number:  " + octal);
    }

    public static void GuessNumbers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        String binary = "";
        while (decimal > 0) {
            int remainder = decimal % 2;
            binary = remainder + binary;
            decimal = decimal / 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Binary number: " + binary);
    }

    public static void allInOne() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        int hex = decimal;
        int oct = decimal;
        int bin = decimal;

        String hexal = "";
        String octal = "";
        String binary = "";

        while (hex > 0 || oct > 0 || bin > 0) {
            if (hex > 0) {
                // Get Hexal
                int hexValue = hex % 16;

                char hexDigit = (hexValue <= 9 && hexValue > 0) ? (char) (hexValue + '0')
                        : (char) (hexValue - 10 + 'A');

                hexal = hexDigit + hexal;

                hex = hex / 16;
            }
            if (oct > 0) {
                // Get Octal
                int remainder = oct % 8;
                octal = remainder + octal;

                oct = oct / 8;
            }
            if (bin > 0) {
                // Get Binary
                int remainder = bin % 2;
                binary = remainder + binary;
                bin = bin / 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The hex number is " + hexal);
        System.out.println("Octal number:  " + octal);
        System.out.println("Binary number: " + binary);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        uncode();
        octal();
        GuessNumbers();
        allInOne();
    }
}
```

I tried to make as little changes to your code as possible.

Comment: ok i see now thank you, now looking at the easier way  makes it look a lot simpler. @Marebre8

Answer (score 0):

Here i convert from decimal to octal,bineary,hexadecimal by calling method getEveryFromDeci(param1,param2) where param1 - any decimal number and param2- its base value like 8,2,16.
    And also i convert octal,bineary,hexadecimal to decimal by calling method allToDeci(param1,param2) where param1 - value of hexadecimal,bineary,octal in string form and param2- base value of hexadecimal

```
private String getEveryFromDeci(Integer x,Integer y){

    List<String> al = deciBin(x,y,new ArrayList<String>());
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(String s : al)
        buffer.append(s);

    return buffer.toString();

}

private List<String> deciBin(Integer a,Integer b,List<String> list){
    if(a>=b){

        deciBin(a/b,b,list);
        list.add(a%b > 9 ? getHexaDecimal(a%b):Integer.toString(a%b));
    }else
        list.add(Integer.toString(a));

    return list;
}

private String getHexaDecimal(int d){
    String s= null;
    switch(d){
    case 10:
        s="A";
        break;
    case 11:
        s="B";
        break;
    case 12:
        s="C";
        break;
    case 13:
        s="D";
        break;
    case 14:
        s="E";
        break;
    case 15:
        s="F";
        break;
    }

    return s;
}

private int allToDeci(String applyNum,int type){
    int sum =0;
    char[] ch = applyNum.toCharArray();
    for(int pum=0;pum<ch.length;pum++)
        sum += Character.isDigit(ch[pum]) ? getAct(ch.length-(pum+1),type) * Character.getNumericValue(ch[pum]) :getAct(ch.length-(pum+1),type) * getNum(ch[pum]);

    return sum;
}

private int getNum(char ch){
    int num = 0;
    switch(ch){
    case 'A':
        num =10;
        break;
    case 'B':
        num = 11;
        break;
    case 'C':
        num =12;
        break;
    case 'D':
        num =13;
        break;
    case 'E':
        num =14;
        break;
    case 'F':
        num=15;
        break;
        default:
            num =Character.getNumericValue(ch);
            break;
    }

    return num;
}

private int getAct(int k,int p){

    int s=1;
    if(k >0){
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
            s *=p;
        return s;
    }else
        return 1;   

}
```